# Pure ECS, How to copy all components from one entity to another

Tags: unity, entity-component-system

I am attempting to create component payloads using prefabs. My goal is to use

`var entity = EntityManagerExtensions.Instantiate(EntityManager, ai_steeringPipelinePrefab[i].Prefab);`

to get all the components I need copied over to another entity (including there data)

The only way i have found so far is to get the component types from the payload entity and add them to the recieving entity with

```
EntityManager.AddComponents(entity, componentTypes);
```

But this does not copy the data.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no exact solution was found instead I opted to add a component to the recieving entity called LinkToPipeline that simply contains the entity so I can look up the components through EntityManager. This works for me because it's only done once during initialization so the performance hit is negligable.